Calculus problem about overlapping spheres
A sphere of radius 1 overlaps a smaller sphere of radius $r$ in such a way that their intersection is a circle of radius r. (In other words, they intersect in a great circle of the small sphere.) Find $r$ so that the volume inside the small sphere and outside the large sphere is as large as possible.
This problem is taken from Stewart's Calculus book and, if needed, see here for the interpretation:
Can someone help me understand this calculus problem means by a few terms?
I proceeded as follows:
The spheres intersection form a circle, so the solid of which I need to find the volume is the spherical cap corresponding to half the smaller sphere minus the intersection of this spherical cap with the larger sphere. (Here I'm not sure I'm right.)
The volume of the spherical cap is half that of the smaller sphere:
$V_{cap} = \frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$.
Using the Phytagorean theorem, I find that the distance from the center of the larger sphere to the center of the smaller sphere is:
$d = \sqrt{1 - r^2}$
The volume of the intersection between the cap and the larger sphere is:
$V_{int} = \int_{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}^1 \pi (1 - y^2) dy = \pi[y - \frac{1}{3}y^3]_{\sqrt{1-r^2}}^1 = \pi[\frac{2}{3} - \sqrt{1 - r^2} + \frac{1}{3}(1 - r^2)^{3/2}]$
The volume I have to maximize is:
$V^* = V_{cap} - V_{int} = \pi[\frac{2}{3}r^3 - \frac{2}{3} + \sqrt{1 - r^2} - \frac{1}{3}(1 - r^2)^{3/2}]$
Computing its derivative and setting it equal to zero I obtain the solution:
$r = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Your answer is correct.
One way to check is to calculate the volume without integration. The intersection volume you mention is equal to the difference between a solid angle sector of the unit sphere and a cone with radius $r$ and (by Pythagoras) height $\sqrt{1 - r^2}$.

The volume of the sphere sector is $\frac{1}{3} (1) A$, where $A = \Omega (1)^2$ is the area of the unit sphere surface encircled by the sector, and $\Omega = 2 \pi (1 - \cos \theta) = 2 \pi \left( 1 - \sqrt{1 - r^2} \right)$ is the solid angle. The volume of the sector is therefore $\frac{2}{3} \pi \left( 1 - \sqrt{1 - r^2} \right)$.
The volume of the cone is simply $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 \sqrt{1 - r^2}$.

So, the intersection volume is
$$V_{\rm int} = \frac{2}{3} \pi - \frac{2}{3} \pi \sqrt{1 - r^2} - \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 \sqrt{1 - r^2}$$
and the desired volume is
$$V = \frac{2}{3} \pi r^3 - V_{\rm int} = \frac{2}{3} \pi r^3 + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 \sqrt{1 - r^2} + \frac{2}{3} \pi \sqrt{1 - r^2} - \frac{2}{3} \pi$$
Differentiating with respect to $r$, we obtain
$$\frac{d V}{d r} = 2 \pi r^2 + \frac{2}{3} \pi r \sqrt{1 - r^2} - \frac{1}{3} \pi \frac{r^3}{\sqrt{1 - r^2}} - \frac{2}{3} \pi \frac{r}{\sqrt{1 - r^2}}$$
$$= \pi r^2 \left[ 2 - \frac{r}{\sqrt{1 - r^2}} \right]$$
The critical points of $V$ are therefore at $r_c = 0$ (which is obviously not a maximum) and when
$$2 - \frac{r_c}{\sqrt{1 - r_c^2}} = 0 \implies r_c^2 = 4 (1 - r_c^2) \implies r_c = \boxed{\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{5}}$$
which can be verified to be a maximum.

Using geometry to verify is great because you do not complicate things, and coming up with a spherical sector was smart. Rearranging terms my $V_{int}$ is actually equal to yours.

@Fra_Ve Indeed, our $V_{\rm int}$ are identical (even though I wrote it in a slightly different way than you). Glad that this was helpful.
